# AWS SES c# sendemailasync task gets cancelled

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-sdk, asp.net-identity-2, amazon-ses

I'm working with asp.net core 2.0 and attempting to send emails through AWS SES using the AWS SDK for .net.

I'm using a very simple bit of code to do this, but for some reason the async task gets cancelled when I'm trying to send. Is there something obvious that I'm missing here? The exception i get from this code says "The operation was cancelled". If I dig into the aggregate exception it specifically says that the Task was cancelled.

Here's my code.

```
public async Task<transactionresponse> sendemail(string subject, string message, string sender, string replyto, List<string> receivers, string[] attachment = null)
    {
        transactionresponse tr = new transactionresponse();
        try
        {
            AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
            sender = (sender == "" ? config.GetSection("appsettings:appemail").Value : sender);
            var dest = new Destination
            {
                ToAddresses = receivers,
            };

            var from = sender;
            var messagesubject = new Content(subject);
            var body = new Body(new Content(message));
            var msg = new Message(messagesubject, body);

            var request = new SendEmailRequest
            {
                Destination = dest,
                Message = msg,
                Source = from
            };
            SendEmailResponse sendit = await client.SendEmailAsync(request);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tr.errors = new string[] { ex.ToString() };
            tr.message = ex.Message;
            tr.iserror = true;
        }
        return tr;
    }
```

Here's the exception:

> "System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFinishSendAsyncError(Exception e, CancellationTokenSource cts)\r\n
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)\r\n
>
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStringAsyncCore(Task`1 getTask)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AsyncHelpers.<>c__DisplayClass1_1`1.<<RunSync>b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
>
>   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AsyncHelpers.ExclusiveSynchronizationContext.BeginMessageLoop() in E:\\JenkinsWorkspaces\\v3-trebuchet-release\\AWSDotNetPublic\\sdk\\src\\Core\\Amazon.Runtime\\Internal\\Util\\_mobile\\AsyncHelpers.cs:line 142\r\n
>
>   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AsyncHelpers.RunSync[T](Func`1 task) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Util\_mobile\AsyncHelpers.cs:line 87\r\n
>   at Amazon.Util.AWSSDKUtils.DownloadStringContent(Uri uri, TimeSpan timeout, IWebProxy proxy) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Util\AWSSDKUtils.cs:line 1000\r\n
>   at Amazon.Util.EC2InstanceMetadata.GetItems(String relativeOrAbsolutePath, Int32 tries, Boolean slurp) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Util\_bcl+coreclr\EC2InstanceMetadata.cs:line 513\r\n
>   at Amazon.Util.EC2InstanceMetadata.get_IAMSecurityCredentials() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Util\_bcl+coreclr\EC2InstanceMetadata.cs:line 311\r\n
>   at Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.FetchCredentials() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Credentials\_bcl+coreclr\DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.cs:line 142\r\n
>   at Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.GetCredentials() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Credentials\_bcl+coreclr\DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.cs:line 88\r\n
>   at Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.GetCredentialsAsync() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Credentials\_bcl+coreclr\DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.cs:line 106\r\n
>   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CredentialsRetriever.cs:line 90\r\n
>   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext) 
>   in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\RetryHandler\RetryHandler.cs:line 137\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n
>   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n
>   at webworxfive.Helpers.messaging.sendemail(String subject, String message, String sender, String replyto, List`1 receivers, String[] attachment) in messaging.cs:line 48"

Comment: Please can you include the full stack trace. Where are you running this from?

Comment: sure I'm running this from my local development machine https://localhost:5001. I've updated the original post with the full stack trace.

Comment: Are you able to access the [region endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html) ([https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/](https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/))? I get a response `<UnknownOperationException/>` if I try with my browser.

Comment: Getting the same but the AWS health dashboard says that it’s up and operating normally. https://status.aws.amazon.com

Comment: Hmm. The only time I've seen this is when I was unable to hit the endpoint and it was timing out. Perhaps you could try the request with something like Fiddler running.

Comment: East 1 https endpoint returning same message.

Comment: After a quick bit of research it said that the unknownoperationexception is expected from raw https requests not generated by the sdk

Comment: Oh, my query was more of a "can you access the endpoint", not a "I think there's something wrong with the endpoint." - I wondered if you were behind a proxy server, firewall, etc. that might be blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured this out on my own. Apparently my application wasn't getting the access key and access secret from my aws sdk profile settings. When I added it to my appsettings and called it into the code the code sent. I seem to remember that it always grabbed the selected profile keys when you had the visual studio plugin installed. Perhaps I was mis remembering.

Thanks for those that commented.